# Neural network loss stops going down

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am training a NN model and the loss stops going down after a while. Although the loss does go down but it is not enough to make good predictions, and I've tried several things but none of them make a lot of difference.

All of my attempts ended up with the loss v.s. steps looking like the figure below, just that the steps it took to flatten may vary:

[image]

Here are the things I already tried:

1. Decreasing learning rate. I swept the learning rate from 1e-3 all the way to 1e-8 and all of them reached the same loss value. Now in my code I even use the tf.train.exponential_decay() so the learning rate decays over steps but it doesn't help.
2. Changing the number of layers (I tried 2 to 4 hidden layers) and nodes of each layer. Not helping to reduce the final loss value as well.
3. Changing the batch size. This did help a little bit. I've swept the batch size from 20000 to 1 and I picked the one that can reach the lowest loss value the fastest, which is batch size of 1000. But again the lowest loss value is the one I am showing the the figure, which is not enough.
4. Changing the regularization coefficient ("beta" in the code). This doesn't really matter since my case isn't facing the problem of overfitting. It is underfitting.

**The following is my code:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import with_statement

#import scipy
from sklearn import preprocessing
from pdb import set_trace as bp

import argparse
import sys
import numpy as np
import csv

import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf


beta = 0.001
training_batch_size = 1000

train_predict_file = "./Data/training_data_3Param.csv"
CV_file = "./Data/CV_data_3Param.csv"
result_file = "hyper_param_result_LRdecay.txt"


def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
  """Model function for Estimator."""

  first_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(features["x"], 100, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)

  second_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(first_hidden_layer, 100, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)

  third_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(second_hidden_layer,100, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)

  fourth_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(third_hidden_layer, 100, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)

  output_layer = tf.layers.dense(fourth_hidden_layer, 3)

  predictions = tf.reshape(output_layer, [-1,3])
  if labels != None:
      labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1,3])

  var = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if "kernel" in v.name]

  # Provide an estimator spec for `ModeKeys.PREDICT`.
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions={"par": predictions})

  # Calculate loss using mean squared error
  regularizer = tf.nn.l2_loss(var[0]) + tf.nn.l2_loss(var[1]) + tf.nn.l2_loss(var[2])

  loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)

  batch = tf.Variable(0)

  learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(
          0.001, #base Learning Rate
          batch * training_batch_size, 
          1e6, #decay step
          0.96, #decay rate
          staircase=True)

  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
      learning_rate=learning_rate)

  train_op = optimizer.minimize( 
      loss=(loss+(beta/2)*regularizer) , global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

  # Calculate root mean squared error as additional eval metric
  eval_metric_ops = {
      "rmse": tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(
          tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), predictions)
  }

  # Provide an estimator spec for `ModeKeys.EVAL` and `ModeKeys.TRAIN` modes.
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode,
      loss=loss,
      train_op=train_op,
      eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


def main(unused_argv):

  train_predict_data_interim = []
  CV_data_interim = []  
  with open(train_predict_file) as f:
      csvreader = csv.reader(f)
      for row in csvreader:
          train_predict_data_interim.append(row)  

  with open(CV_file) as f:
      csvreader = csv.reader(f)
      for row in csvreader:
          CV_data_interim.append(row)  


  train_predict_data_interim = pd.DataFrame(train_predict_data_interim)
  CV_data_interim = pd.DataFrame(CV_data_interim)
  min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))

  train_predict_data_transformed = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(train_predict_data_interim) 
  CV_data_transformed = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(CV_data_interim)

  train_predict_data_transformed = pd.DataFrame(train_predict_data_transformed)
  CV_data_transformed = pd.DataFrame(CV_data_transformed)

  train_data_interim = train_predict_data_transformed.sample(frac=0.9996875)
  predict_data_interim = train_predict_data_transformed.loc[~train_predict_data_transformed.index.isin(train_data_interim.index), :]

  a = len(train_predict_data_transformed.columns)
  train_labels_interim = train_data_interim.iloc[:, a-3:a] 
  train_features_interim = train_data_interim.iloc[:, :a-3] 
  train_features_numpy = np.asarray(train_features_interim, dtype=np.float32)
  train_labels_numpy = np.asarray(train_labels_interim, dtype=np.float32)


  # Instantiate Estimator
  nn = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/nmos_3Param_LRdecay_bs%s_beta%s" %(training_batch_size, beta))
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": train_features_numpy},
      y=train_labels_numpy,
      batch_size = training_batch_size,
      num_epochs= None,
      shuffle=True)

  # Train
  nn.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=448000)

  test_features_interim = CV_data_transformed.iloc[:, :a-3]
  test_features_numpy = np.asarray(test_features_interim, dtype=np.float32)

  test_labels_interim = CV_data_transformed.iloc[:, a-3:a]
  test_labels_numpy = np.asarray(test_labels_interim, dtype=np.float32)

  # Score accuracy
  test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": test_features_numpy},
      y=test_labels_numpy,
      batch_size = 1,
      num_epochs= 1,
      shuffle=False)

  ev = nn.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn)
  print("Loss: %s" % ev["loss"])
  print("Root Mean Squared Error: %s" % ev["rmse"])


  prediction_features_interim = predict_data_interim.iloc[:, :a-3]
  prediction_features_numpy = np.asarray(prediction_features_interim, dtype=np.float32)
  prediction_labels_interim = predict_data_interim.iloc[:, a-3:a]
  prediction_labels_numpy = np.asarray(prediction_labels_interim, dtype=np.float32)

  print ('-' * 30, 'prediction_labels_numpy', '-' * 30)
  print (prediction_labels_numpy)
  prediction_lables_str = np.char.mod('%f',prediction_labels_numpy)

  with open(result_file,'a') as f:
      f.write('-' * 50)
      f.write('\n')
      f.write("batch_size = %s beta = %s\n" %(training_batch_size, beta))
      f.write("Loss: %s\n" % ev["loss"])
      f.write("Root Mean Squared Error: %s\n" % ev["rmse"])
      f.write("%s\n" %(prediction_lables_str))

  # Print out predictions
  predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x= {"x": prediction_features_numpy},
      num_epochs=1,
      batch_size = 1,
      shuffle=False)
  predictions = nn.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn)#, yield_single_examples=False)
  for i, p in enumerate(predictions):
    print("Prediction %s: %s" % (i + 1, p["par"]))
    with open(result_file,'a') as f:
        f.write("Prediction %s: %s \n" % (i + 1, p["par"]))




if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.register("type", "bool", lambda v: v.lower() == "true")
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

A big portion of main() is normalizing data into the range of (-1,1), both training data and cross validation data.

**The raw training data looks like :**

[image]

**To be more illustrative with plot, I plot the training data (features)**:
[image]

Basically one row of the data represents a line in the plot. The first 65 columns are the features and the last three columns of the data are the labels, which is not plotted. So **this is an NN regression case with 65 inputs and 3 outputs.**

I can still try something else like:

1. Use different activation functions.
2. I don't think increasing the amount of training sets would work since the CV loss is similar to the training error, but I can try.
3. Do feature cross ( like multiplying feature 1 and 2, etc.)?

But I would happily have some experts take a look at the case and maybe I am missing something obvious here. Please share your thoughts and I appreciate any kind of discussions. Thank you!

Comment: Loss meaning training loss or test loss?

Comment: Try replacing GradientDescentOptimizer with AdamOptimizer. Start with the default learning rate and see if you get better results.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn (I asked the question to be closed though, it's OT).

Comment: @Denziloe, here I mean training loss. The test loss ( CV loss) is very similar to train loss once the train loss flattened.

Comment: @catastrophic-failure What does OT mean?

Comment: It means Off-topic, i.e. it doesn't conform to the scope of the site.

Comment: It's pretty hard to look at your code and give you a clear cut reason why your network is not performing. Generally though, you should first make sure each piece of your neural network is doing what it's supposed to be doing. A lot of times when I find a neural network to be "stuck" or the loss diverges or something funky like that happening, it's because I've messed up the data input stage somehow. For example, if I am input one-hot vectors, I might have forgotten to re-zero them after every batch. After verifying all pieces are working as intended, then look into hyperparameter tuning.

Comment: @enumaris, I did verify the structure by training 65 features to 1 label and it worked pretty well ( both the training loss and CV loss are pretty low).